# How do I change my phonon backed to phonon-vlc?

Tags: xubuntu, vlc, phonon

I have the [Tomahawk music player](https://www.tomahawk-player.org/) installed on Xubuntu 14.04
The application allows me to play tracks from Spotify, Soundcloud, etc. However, Spotify tracks are not working and I was told, after contacting the Tomahawk developers, to try and switch my phonon backend to phonon-vlc.
Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to change this in the Xubuntu settings manager.
How do I switch to phonon-vlc, using either the command line or the settings manager(since it is possible that I may have missed it)?
Edit: I should note that I already have phonon-backend-vlc installed

Comment: Apparently, installing `phonon-backend-vlc` will *install* the backend. But the settings for Phonon are KDE apps.

Comment: Is there anyway to edit the phonon settings in xfce or should I get back in contact with the developers of Tomahawk? edit: I should note that I already have phonon-backend-vlc installed

Comment: I've searched - but there's nothing - not even a config file, a dbus interface, nothing. Looks like we can find the call to change it by examining the KDE System Settings app's source code.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't found anything either about it. In any case thanks for the help.

Comment: Mint 18.1, I just installed phonon-backend-vlc and it started to play music.

Answer (score 0):

OP here with a potential answer. 
After checking up on the bugs page of the tomahawk music player on github, I stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/tomahawk-player/tomahawk/issues/474).
I simply installed kdeconnect on my computer and the spotify tracks in tomahawk worked.
The OP of the bug believes it has something to do with the kde libraries and dependencies, but I still have no idea. If anyone wants to help explain why this works, it could be very helpful to someone else with this problem.